# same database structure and index, but different query speed and explain results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL databases on 2 separate cloud servers. One is setup by my colleague and I duplicated that one with same structures.

Days ago I found a query on my database is slow but fast in his database. Then he told me he added 2 indexes for a table and he added the same 2 indexes for my database but it just didn't work and he didn't know why.
The `explain` result is different after adding the same indexes. And my query is still slow.
(`0.36s` vs `> 3mins`)

**Could you tell me what's wrong and help me understand the `explain` result and the differences ?**

---

Query:

```
select sum(A.money) from 
stat_sword.t_pay_history_real as A, 
inner join
(select uid, reg_srv_id as srv_id 
     from sword_common.t_ids
     where reg_srv_id < 100000
     group by uid having count(uid) > 1) as B 
on A.uid = B.uid and A.srv_id = B.srv_id
```

table strcuture:

```
# Same t_pay_history_real for both databases

mysql> show create table stat_sword.t_pay_history_real \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t_pay_history_real
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_pay_history_real` (
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `srv_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ingot` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `rid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `span_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `orderid` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`,`srv_id`,`uid`,`orderid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

# My sword_common.t_ids
```

mysql> show create table sword_common.t_ids \G;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t_ids
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_ids` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_srv_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `span_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `cur_srv_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `com_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`reg_srv_id`),
  KEY `idx_rid` (`rid`),
  KEY `idx_uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

His sword_common.t_ids

```
mysql> show create table sword_common.t_ids \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t_ids
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_ids` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_srv_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `span_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `cur_srv_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `com_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`reg_srv_id`),
  KEY `inx_rid` (`rid`),
  KEY `inx_uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`Explain` result of the above query:

On my DB:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  26778 |                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | A          | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 162010 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t_ids      | index | NULL          | idx_uid | 4       | NULL | 335827 | Using where; Using index       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

On his DB:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys           | key         | key_len | ref                                  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | A          | ALL   | NULL                    | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                 | 315144 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref   | <auto_key0>             | <auto_key0> | 8       | stat_sword.A.uid,stat_sword.A.srv_id |     10 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t_ids      | index | PRIMARY,inx_rid,inx_uid | inx_uid     | 4       | NULL                                 | 740388 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Each table row count: https://dpaste.com/AZ5KU4JCV

---

The above query takes `0.36s` in his db but more than `3 mins` in mine..

Why the `explain` result and order are different and what does it say? I just learnt some basic about index and am not familiar with `explain` result at all.

<s>Also, I was planning to try a composite index with `(rid, uid)` if I succeeded speeding up the query by adding the same indexes but I failed.</s>  (I read the indexes wrong and this is totally useless.)

---

Update:

Ok. The MySQL verion is different, mine is `Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution` and his is `Server version: 5.6.48 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`.. I would dump the data from my DB and try on his MySQL for now...

Comment: Your MySQL server is more than seven years old - you should check whether you want to update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t_pay_history_real` needs `INDEX(uid, srv_id)`

`t_ids` might be helped by `INDEX(reg_srv_id, uid)`

Note that you are running different versions: `<auto_key0>` indicates a newer version.

Switching from `ENGINE=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=InnoDB` should be beneficial in many ways.

If you add `INDEX(rid, uid)`, remove `INDEX(rid)` as being useless.  However I don't see any need for it for *this* query.

Comment: Sorry about being so late to accept your answer. I've been learning related knowledge, `explain` output, index etc... You are right that `INDEX(rid, uid)` is useless. I misread before. And your advice on adding `INDEX(uid, srv_id)` solves everything. Now it takes less than `1s` to finish the query. Thanks !

Comment: I still have 2 questions on your answer: 1. Why *"`t_ids` might be helped by `INDEX(reg_srv_id, uid)`"*  since there's `PRIMARY KEY (uid,reg_srv_i),` ?

Comment: 2. How does *"Switching from `ENGINE=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=InnoDB`"* would be beneficial in many ways ?

Comment: @Rick - The order of columns in any index (including a PK) matters.  Think about looking up a person by lastname in a list ('index') that is sorted by first name _then_ last name.

Comment: @Rick - Engine:  there are dozens of discussions on why InnoDB is preferred; none of the reasons necessarily apply in _this_ case.

Answer (score 6):

The giveaway is the `<auto_key0>` key used in the derived table on your friend's server. This is not a key created by your friend, this is a key generated by mysql automatically as part of [subquery materialization optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) technique.

This optimization technique was added in [mysql v5.6.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html), therefore your ancient mysql version can't take advantage of it. It is time to upgrade! Both of you...

Comment: It took me days of my free time on learning related knowledges, including the `explain` output meaning (The MySQL doc is far from good and I watched an 1 hour [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoLoIFW1H6g&t=1521s&ab_channel=Percona) on explaning that) . Now I understand enough details and come back to say thanks! But I would like to accept @Rick James 's answer since he enlightened me how to solve this problem with my MYSQL version. Again, thank you ;).

Comment: @Rick I understand why you accepted the other answer - just bear in mind that you asked a question explaining you the difference between the two plans and not how to solve it in your mysql version! So, the accepted answer does not answer what you asked. It is a useful answer, but not an answer to your question!

Comment: haha I know (～￣▽￣)～. Take it easy, I like you too!